# How to find/insert data in missing sequence(auto increment) ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains

```
ID(P)(auto)  NAME
----------------------- 
1            Art
4            Bankie
6            Cara
```

The data sequence has 3 missing ID values: 2, 3 and 5.

This is my query:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO applicants ($fname) VALUES ('$fname')");
```

How can data be INSERTed in place of a missing ID value, in order to use all ID's.

Comment: From a SQL point, you need to do three things. Stop the AutoInc, make the INSERTs, enable the AutoInc again. But why did you use the php tag?

Comment: stop autoinc is a bad idea.

Comment: You can also manually INSERT the data, or even adjust the auto_increment value.

Comment: @BrandonWhite. why you would stop and insert manually? bad idea.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It can't pull the data from nowhere... If you are talking about holes due to InnoDB "INSERT IGNORE" that is a different story. Could you elaborate on your question, so we might actually propose a decent solution. Furthermore, what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: check my update. I'm inserting a data then display it and have a delete button.

Comment: Just so I understand, you HAD data in the missing values that you deleted, and now you want to place new data in their place?

Comment: yup that's the point. so all the ID will be useful no missing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not necessary for performance purposes, however to my knowledge there isn't a way to do this automatically. You would have to check for the missing ID ranges and assign them manually.

I would also recommend looking at the following post about SQL injection protection as it's a necessary step to maintaining a secure database connection. [SQL Injection Prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Secondly, please do not use php's mysql_query() functions. These are deprecated and have been for some time now. MySQLi or PDO is recommended instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's could be done using variable in sql query.

Let's say `$name = $_POST['fname'];`

Then you need insert query like this :

```
insert into yourtable(id,name)
select id-diff as new_id,'$name' from(
    select id,id - (@x := @x + 1) as diff
    from yourtable
    join (select @x := 0) as t1
    order by id asc
) as t2
where diff <> 0
limit 1
```